# Algorithm to determine whether two elements of S exist whose sum is exactly x

Tags: algorithms

Given a set $S$ containing $n$ real numbers and a real number $x$. We seek an algorithm to determine
whether two elements of $S$ exist whose sum is exactly $x$.

1. Assume that $S$ is unsorted. Give an $O(n \log n)$ algorithm for the
   problem.
2. Assume that $S$ is sorted. Give an $O(n)$ algorithm for the problem.

Comment: Hint: Once you have the second one, you can get the other by first sorting the list.

Comment: The problem is slightly easier if it is assumed all elements of $S$ are distinct.